# Vectorizing a for loop in MATLAB/Octave 

Tags: matlab, octave

My question is: is there a way to vectorize this operation in MATLAB/Octave?

```
y = %a (m x 1) vector, with every entry in [1, 10]
y2 = repmat(1 : 10, [m 1]);
for i = 1 : m
    y2(i, :) = (y2(i, :) == y(i));
end
```

Comment: @macduff: I don't seem to get the correct result with `kron`.

Comment: @Jonas, thanks for questioning me, I got a little hasty with my comment.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bsxfun` is a good way of both expanding and vectorizing computations (it will perform a multithreaded computation if it's beneficial).

```
m = 10;

y = randperm(m);

y2 = bsxfun(@eq,y,(1:m)')';
```

Comment: @JoseRamirez: Please consider accepting the answer if you consider it helpful